# sftp - how to connect to non-default port?

Tags: command-line, ssh, sftp

I want to connect to server via sftp using specific IP and a specific (non-default) PORT .

How can I choose non-default port when connecting using `sftp`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use the `-oPort=port_number` option

```
sftp -oPort=port_number host_name
```

> [man sftp](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/sftp.1.html)
>
> **sftp - secure file transfer program**
>
> sftp [-1Cv] [-B buffer_size] [-b batchfile] [-F ssh_config] [-o
>   ssh_option] [-P sftp_server_path] [-R num_requests] [-S program] [-s
>   subsystem | sftp_server] host
>
> **-o ssh_option**
>  Can be used to pass options to ssh in the format used in ssh_config(5). This is useful for specifying options for which
>   there is no separate sftp command-line flag. For example, to specify
>   an alternate port use: `sftp -oPort=24`. For full details of the
>   options listed below, and their possible values, see ssh_config(5).

Comment: I got the answer :

sftp://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:port

ex. sftp://158.45.47.66:4343

Comment: @MeetVaishnani - do you need to access the `sftp` server using a browser or using a terminal/command-line?

Comment: I want to use it from browser.

Comment: @MeetVaishnani - Okay - understood. you might want to add your comment, as an answer to your question.

Comment: Worth noting: sftp foo@host.tld -oPort=1234 will *not* work, you have to put the ssh option before the user@host

Comment: @DM8 - who did you refer your comment to? I think that in my answer the port parameter is before the host_name parameter

Comment: @Yaron ...myself and anyone like me headscratching trying to figure it out :)

Answer (score 12):

You can use **-P** option or **-oPort** option to SFTP to a server from a specific port.

```
sftp -oPort=port_no username@x.x.x.x

eg. sftp -oPort=8022 rahul@x.x.x.x
```

or

```
sftp -P port_no username@x.x.x.x

eg. sftp -P 8022 rahul@x.x.x.x
```

Note that -P is capital P not small